# java Cannot view image src in html when loaded from package

Tags: java, html

In my project, I have created a package that I am calling htmlRepository. In this package, I have created an Html file called mapping.html and I have added to this package also an image called mapping.jpg that is being called from the mapping.html as
`<IMG SRC="file:mapping.jpg"    width="2000" height="40" >`
I am accessing this HTML file from htmlRepository and converting it to a url and then I use the setPage method to diplay it in a JEditorPane.I am obtaining the HTML file URL using the code below:

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
```

and then I pass the URL to the setPage method.

When I launch my project using eclipse I can see both the HTML text and image in my JEditorPane, however, when I launch my project jar file I only see the HTML text, and the image is left out. Which would be the correct way to do this so I can view the image even when am using the project jar file?

Answer (score 1):

i have resolved as i was doing a little trial and error.i removed "file:" and left it as  and now everything is working fine.